# how to use listview to fetch the record from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I create database and one table **TABLE_NAME**. I need to fetch all record from
this table to list view. after this list view should be enable for
delete the record. i am novice at android and i don't know how to use the list view.
Please Provide me some code or reference.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this class for create and copy Database and also get and delete records..
http://code.google.com/p/nithin-warriers-code-base/source/browse/trunk/SampleDatabase/src/com/smartandroidians/database/DBHelper.java?spec=svn10&r=10

after implement this class u need to add get and delete finction to this class..
if any query ask freely...

Comment: http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-creating-a-sqlite-database
please see this also helps u..

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use a '[CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)' to link the database and the ListView. For more check out this example: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html